# Formatting HTML correctly from cURL requests

Tags: php, html, curl

I am working on an applet that allows the user to input a URL to a news article or other webpage (in Japanese) and view the contents of that page within an iFrame in my page. The idea is that once the content is loaded into the page, the user can highlight words using their cursor, which stores the selected text in an array (for translating/adding to a personal dictionary of terms) and surrounds the text in a red box (div) according to a stylesheet defined on my domain.  To do this, I use cURL to retrieve the HTML of the external page and dump it into the source of the iFrame.

However, I keep running into major formatting problems with the retrieved HTML. The big problem is preserving style sheets, and to fix this, I've used DOMDocument to add  tags to the  section of the retrieved HTML.  This works for *some* pages/URLs, but there are still lots of style problems with the output HTML for many others. For example, div layers crash into each other, alignments are off, and backgrounds are missing.  This is made a bit more problematic as I need to embed the output HTML into a new  in order to make the onClick javascript function for passing text selections in the embedded content to work, which means the resulting source ends up looking like this:

```
<div onclick="parent.selectionFunction()" id ="studyContentn">

<!-- HTML of output from cURL, including doctype declarations and <html>,<head> tags -->

</div>
```

It seems like for the most part a lot of the formatting issues I keep running into are largely arbitrary. I've tried using php Tidy to clean output from HTML, but that also only works for some pages but not many others. I've got a slight suspicion it may have to do with CDATA declarations that get parsed oddly when working with DOMDocument, but I am not certain.

Is there a way I can guarantee that HTML output from cURL will be rendered correctly and faithfully in all instances? Or is there perhaps a better way of going about doing this? I've tried a bunch of different ways of approaching this issue, and each gets closer to a solution but brings its own new problems as well.

Thanks -- let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to pull the html of a complete web page and display it under your domain, in your html. This is always going to be tricky, a lot of java script will break, relative url's will be wrong and as you mentioned, styles as well. Your probably also changing the dimensions that the page is displayed in. These can all be worked around but your going to be fighting an uphill battle with each new site, or if a current site change design

I'd probably take a different approach to the problem. You might want to write a browser plugin as the interface to the external web site instead. Then your applet can sit on top of the functional and tested (hopefully) site. Then you can focus on what you need to do for your applet rather than a never ending list of fiddly html issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do a similar thing. It is very difficult to conserve the formatting, and the JS scripts in webpage complicated the thing. I finally gave up the complete the idea of completely displaying the original format, but do it with a workaround:

1. Select only headers, links, lists, paragraph which you are interested at.
2. Add the domain path of your ownsite to links.
3. You may wrap the headers, links etc. items by your own class.
4. Display it
   in your case you want to select text and store it, which is another topic. What I did is to parse the HTMl in two levels, and then it is easy to do the selection. Keep in mind IE and Firefox/Chrome needs to be dealt with separately.